# Packaging an .exe file to MSIX and signing it

Tags: windows, exe, msix

I have developed an application and want to publish to the microsoft store. I have tried using advanced installer but unless I pay $500 I cannot publish it i think using the trial version? I have also tried using MSIX Package (Windows) but then I need to digitally sign it, and then I can't add logos and etc. I also do not know how to get a certificate and convert it to .pfx format for this to work.

Honestly, this process has just made me want to stop, which is unfortunate. So I am trying to find a service or someone that I can pay to package my .exe app to an MSIX, signed and everything so that I can just upload it to the store on my account..but I cannot find anything on google.

Does anyone know of a service, or even a better application that has better guides for MSIX packaging and signing? Advanced Installer is pretty extensive, but their guides are based on MSI, not MSIX. Not worth paying $500 for when they are not even current with Microsoft Stores required format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI - to get a useful answer around here it helps if you place specific questions (i.e. split your question into multiple ones, like: *Do I need to digitally sign an application for the MS Store?; how do I add logos...?)*

Back to your problem. I work on the Advanced Installer and I will try to give you some advice to help clear a part of your problems.

1. First of all, to **publish an application in the Microsoft Store you don't need a certificate**. As explained in [our guide](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-publish-microsoft-store.html), in your Store developer account you will find a package identity assigned to your application, here is an example:

[image]

The value that starts with **CN=...** must be copied and pasted into your Advanced Installer project, on the **Package Information** page, under the ID field. Make sure Digital Signing is disabled in your project. (You need to digitally sign the MSIX only when you deploy it outside the MS Store)

This identity will allow the MS team to certify you as the owner of the application. Once Microsoft approves your application submission, the MSIX package you upload will be signed with a Microsoft digital certificate. All MSIX packages uploaded in the store are signed by Microsoft.

2. I don't know how complex your application is, but most apps can be packaged with the [free Advanced Installer Express edition](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/express-edition.html). Have you tried that? The commercial editions include additional features, but you might not need them.

Comment: Thank you so much for this comment. It was insightful to not only future posts (i.e. the be more specific) but also gave an attempt at answering it either way. And I think that solves my issue. I was not using the CN from my microsoft account. Very much appreciated!

Comment: @Bogdan, do you know if Microsoft will sign MSI installs for free, or is it only free for MSIX installs?

Comment: I don't know if they will offer such a service for free, it might not go well with their partners selling certificates. What they are currently offering in a partially free way is the Azure Code Signing service, which you can use to sign an MSI. This service is in preview at the moment, and for the moment it is free if you already have an Azure Subscription. We don't know when it will be generally available or what pricing will it have then.

Answer (score 0):

[MSIX Hero](https://msixhero.net/) is pretty great and is open source. Assuming your application is just a directory of files containing one or more EXEs just click "pack directory to MSIX"

[image: Image of "pack directory to MSIX" button in MSIX Hero]

Then select the folder containing your application files and the EXEs you want to create shortcuts for in the start menu. It will pull a lot of the package metadata from the metadata in the EXEs.

[image: Pack MSIX dialogue]

If you are publishing to the Windows store you don't need to sign the package.

If you do want to sign it for distribution outside the store the options for that are pretty easy to use as well. The only issue is you will need a code signing certificate, which is ~$300 a year.